# Unable to find class in my logging.php file

Tags: laravel

I'm currently exploring the Laraval 9 custom log (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/logging)

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    // return view('welcome');

    Log::channel('abuse')->info('API endpoint abuse', [
        'user_id' => 2
    ]);
});
```

Inside my logging.php and I also define the "use App\Logging\SimpleFormatter;" at the top inside the logging.php:

[image]

Inside my SimpleFormatter class:
[image]

But when I trigger the log an error come out:

```
[2022-11-18 09:02:31] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [App\\Logging\\SimpleFormatter] does not exist. at /Users/Shared/laravel-sanctum-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:877)
[stacktrace]
```

I follow the step 100%, but this error keeps popping. Please need an advise how to deal with this issue.

Solution:
Make sure to check class directory is correct when using the class.

Comment: Make sure the file is in `app/Logging/SimpleFormatter.php` (case sensitive). Also run `composer dump-autoload` and check if there are any errors

Comment: Thank you bro, I put the Logging file outside of the app folder. I'm so freaking dumb.

Answer (score 0):

> Inside my logging.php and I also define the "use
> App\Logging\SimpleFormatter;" at the top inside the logging.php

You do not have to do this, just leave the `use App\Logging\SimpleFormatter;` and in your config simply set the tap value to:

```php
'tap' => [SimpleFormatter::class],
```

Additionally try to run a `composer dump-autoload` after these changes.